# How do I use some bootstrap snippets?

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

I'm having problem to use markup. based on [this snippet code](http://www.codeply.com/go/yq5hGEJ8L6)

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Thumbnail Headline</h4>
                    <p>short thumbnail description</p>
                    <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Zoom">Zoom</a>
                    <a href="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Download now">Download</a></p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/1/" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Thumbnail Headline</h4>
                    <p>short thumbnail description</p>
                    <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Zoom">Zoom</a>
                    <a href="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Download now">Download</a></p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/2/" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Thumbnail Headline</h4>
                    <p>short thumbnail description</p>
                    <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Zoom">Zoom</a>
                    <a href="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Download now">Download</a></p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/3/" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">            
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Thumbnail Headline</h4>
                    <p>short thumbnail description</p>
                    <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Zoom">Zoom</a>
                    <a href="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Download now">Download</a></p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/4/" alt="...">
            </div>
      </div>        

  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

What I did is:

1. Add the CSS code file into my theme folder and insert a line (`stylesheets[all][] = css/custom.css`) in .info file that point to it.
2. Add the js code file into my theme folder and insert a line (`scripts[] = js/custom.js`) in .info file that point to it.
3. Copy and paste the html code into my ckeditor (as a source) block body.
4. Check the Popovers and Tooltips (hover and focus trigger are ticked) option in theme option to make sure they are enabled. Although, I tested and added the following code, but nothing happened.

   ```
   function($) {
     $(function() {
       $(document).tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' });
       $(document).popover({ selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]' });
     });
   })(jQuery);
   ```

I checked the HTML output; the CSS file loaded properly, but in the output I just see the picture and styles, but when I hover over the pictures, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we should put the the js code inside a function like this

```
(function ($) {   
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    
    $('.thumbnail').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
        }
    ); 
});
}(jQuery));
```